# How to find specific lines in a file and then replace a word from those lines keeping everything else intact using vi/vim editor

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi, substitution

I have a random file with a bunch of lines. Snippet:

```
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text cold
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text hot
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text tea
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text bee
```

etc

I want to match every line starting with `lorium0{([y])}` and then replace `simply` with `very` using the vi or vim editor (Preferably with vi). Would like to accomplish this with a **1 line command**.

1. Find Regex match to filter out unwanted lines
2. Find word **simply** and replace with **very**

ie.:

```
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text bee
Becomes:
lorium0{([y])} Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not very random text bee
```

Trying:

```
:1,$ s\(lorium0[^ ].*\)\1\(simply\)\2\1: very\2g
```

But having difficulty formatting the command and understanding capture groups in substitution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `:g` with a pattern to restrict the lines on which the replacement is made.  For example:

```
:g/^lorium0{(\[y\])}/s/simply/very
```

This is the classic solution, following the pattern `g/pattern/command`.  (When "pattern" is replaced by "re" (regex) and the command is "p" (print), this becomes `g/re/p` and you see why the popular command is named `grep`.) The buffer is searched globally, and the command is applied to any line which matches the pattern.  For more information, use `:help :global`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
:%s/^lorium0{(\[y])}.*\zs\<simply\>/very/g
```

Or,

```
:%s/\(^lorium0{(\[y])}.*\)\@<=\<simply\>/very/g
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string/line
- `lorium0{(\[y])}` - a literal `lorium0{([y])}` text
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\zs` - the text before is just context, the match starts at this point
- OR `\(^lorium0{(\[y])}.*\)\@<=` matches a location that is immediately preceded with the `^lorium0{(\[y])}.*` pattern
- `\<simply\>` - a whole word `simply` (`\<` and `\>` are word boundaries).

Or, you may use a group (in the regex) with a backreference (in the RHS):

```
%s/^\(lorium0{(\[y])}.*\)\<simply\>/\1very/g
    ^^                 ^^           ^^
```

However, this will only replace the last occurrence of `simply` on the line.

Comment: Seems to not work for me. I get Pattern not found error. Tried on both vi and vim.

Comment: Works on linux but not on unix. Is there anything specific I need to add for it to work on unix?

Comment: @Data I tested in Vim on my Ubuntu before posting. Try `%s/^\(lorium0{(\[y])}.*\)\<simply\>/\1very/g`

Comment: Nice! That worked on unix, brill!

Comment: @Data I added this variation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there anything that can be done if you see Trailing Character errors?
For instance, if you were to replace `<this_is\>` with `this_is_it` using the same logic.
I've tried backslashing but still get the error.

Comment: @Data If you need to replace chunks of chars that is are not natural language words, do not use word boundaries, remove `\<` and `\>` from my pattern. Note that you need to double the backslash to match a literal backslash, and to match literal `<` and `>` you should use just `<` and `>`, do not escape them.

Comment: So if you have:
`lorium0{([y])}-hu-.job/ Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply_tee random text bee`.

Like this?
`:%s/^\(lorium0{(\[y])}*/.*\)<simply_tee>/\1very_tee_tree/g`
?

Comment: @Data Please read my above comment to understand that you must be careful with escaping `<` and `>` chars. Use `%s/^\(lorium0{(\[y])}.*\)\<simply_tee\>/\1very_tee_tree/g`

Comment: To would-be upvoters: while this answer effectively solves OP's problem, the other answer is a much better fit for the question *as it was asked*.